# Dynamically create database in cPanel?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cpanel

**database.php - config**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sample',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'db_sample',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('Test_model');

        $sample = $this->Test_model->test();

        echo $sample;
    }

}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    public function test() {
        $sql = "SELECT name
        FROM company";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $num = $query->num_rows();

        $this->load->dbforge();
        if($this->dbforge->create_database('service_test')) {
            $this->db->query("Use service_test");
            $this->db->query("CREATE USER 'user1'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'admin123';");
            $this->db->query("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON service_test.* TO user1@localhost identified by 'admin123';");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }
}

?>
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1044

Access denied for user 'sample'@'localhost' to database 'service_test'

CREATE DATABASE `service_test` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Is there any configuration setting that I'm missing?
I've been struggling with this for 2 days. I have sent a help ticket but they simply told me that the privileged user and database in question must be under the same cPanel account (and they are, as far as I know).
The **sample** user has all the privileges enabled for it. We manually set it up.

Comment: check your database server name. On Serer it cannot be localhost. Confirm with your DB Administrator.

Comment: as the message says `'sample'@'localhost'` don't have database creation permission. Do you really got permission on your user to create database? try opening up a console from your account and try to create a database.

Comment: @Vinay on server the server name is normally `localhost` unless configured in a weird way.

Comment: I forget to told, but we cannot create new user on server without the permission of DB Administrator.

Comment: @Vinay based on what i've found on google, i can use 'localhost' when i upload my project to the server for cPanel. i wouldn't know what else to put there, tried adding the port as well to no avail.

Comment: Your database should already have a permission to this user. You do not have a grant to grant permission.

Comment: @bansi i manually set up the sample user, had all the privileges checked. basically we have a 'static' database, db_sample, that serves as the 'mother' database <- the sample user has all the privileges for this database. it's the first thing i access. then i try to create a new database through it, but i keep getting the access denied message.

Comment: @Vinay sorry, your last comment about not having a grant to grant permission is quite vague, didnt quite get that, would you mind explaining it further?

Comment: You already have that user. Do not need to create again and grant. If you are doing it on localhost then it would be fine to do. But on servers they gives only to use the one user else you can create multiple database.

Comment: @Vinay yes, i was able to achieve it offline, i started encountering the problem when i put it up on the live server. i've tried it even without creating another user, and still got the same error. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Are you able to create multidatabase manually there on live server?

Comment: @Vinay yes, in fact therer are three right now that we manually created

Comment: I don't think any database administrator will give create permission on shared database, unless you own the server or the database server is running on your cloud. Try to open up phpmyadmin from your cpanel and try to create a database from there. (you may have permission to create database from cpanel, but that don't count as cpanel mostly runs in elevated privilege)

Comment: So why do you think it will generate for you automatically?

Comment: @bansi I went to phpmyadmin and unfortunately yes, i don't see any options there to create a new database. so what should be the next step?

Comment: @Vinay honestly, I don't know. I'm new to cPanel and was just assigned this task of dynamic database creation (it's for security purposes, apparently. compartmentalization of information of clients)

Comment: cpanel has this kind of security built in where for the most part you cannot create databases directly, you need to use the panel. In order to create databases you need a root-level user... If you do not have this then there isn't much you can do about it...